# Prevent frame from moving without locking it

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

Is there a way to prevent a text frame (more specifically, the primary frame) from moving (by accident), apart from locking it?

Yes, I can simply lock it, but this affects search and replace, this is why I look for another solution.

Comment: Not that i know of. Wouldn it be just easier to unlock all search and relock though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really. An object (eg. text frame) is either locked, or unlocked.

Alternatively, you can move the text frame to a separate layer, lock the layer, but keep the text frame unlocked, and everytime you need to search & replace, you would have to manually unlock the layer, make the edits, then lock the layer back.

I have used this method for multi-language docs, where the text frames for each language sit on separate, locked layers, while having the artwork (graphics) on the base (bottom most) layer.

[image]

Comment: ps. but I can see your point, and I agree this would be a very useful feature if ID had a way to lock the movement of text frames, without locking the ability to make edits